# python selenium phantomJS element.location returns wrong location

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have problem with python selenium phantomjs which i couldn't solve. element.location returns wrong location. when I see cropped image it is showing part of desired image and also unwanted one. It worked on firefox perfectly but doesn't work on phantomjs.

Here is code:

```
def screenOfElement(self, _element):
    _location = _element.location
    _size = _element.size
    _wholePage = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(base64.decodestring(self.webdriver.get_screenshot_as_base64())))

    _left = _location['x']
    _top = _location['y']
    _right = _location['x'] + _size['width']
    _bottom = _location['y'] + _size['height']

    return _wholePage.crop((_left, _top, _right, _bottom))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found only one solution that worked.

**Method 1:**

1) Hide everything except needed element:

```
with open('jquery-2.2.3.min.js', 'r') as jquery_js: 
    jquery = jquery_js.read() #read the jquery from a file
    self.webdriver.execute_script(jquery) #active the jquery lib
    self.webdriver.execute_script("""
        element = $('#mydiv').parent();
        while(element.parent().length)
        {
            element.parent().siblings().hide();
            element = element.parent();
        }
    """)
```

2) Take screenshot.

3) Show every element that we hid:

```
self.webdriver.execute_script("""
    element = $('#mydiv').parent();
    while(element.parent().length)
    {
        element.parent().siblings().show();
        element = element.parent();
    }
""")
```

But the issue with that is, after we show all element, we might show ones that were hidden before. Also sometimes it doesn't work.

If you are using phantomJS probably visual parts doesn't matter. So better solution would be to

**Method 2:**

1) Move needed element directly inside `<body>`:

```
$('body').append($('#mydiv'))
```

2) Hide all element except needed one:

```
$('body > :not("#mydiv")').hide();
```

3) Show again:

```
$('body > *)').show();
```

Hope this helps who has encountered same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your PhantomJS window might be too small.

Try:
`driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
 driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024)`